# How to get files from external storage in Flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I want to get all file in listview with flutter project but how to access the external folder.

I have created a folder with name 'MyFile' and it is created at "/storage/emulated/0/MyFile",

but below code pointing at "/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.demo/MyFile".

I don't know why below code is not working

```
 Directory externalDirectory = await getExternalStorageDirectory();
 print('External Storage:$externalDirectory');
 // External storage: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.demo/MyFile
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When using Flutter Official [path_provider](https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider#-readme-tab-) package, getExternalStorageDirectory() will always return path to  /storage/emulated/0/**your-package-name**/files.

To get **/storage/emulated/0/**, you can used a Third-party package [ext_storage](https://pub.dev/packages/ext_storage). Below code will return your desired Directory path

```
 var externalDirectoryPath = await ExtStorage.getExternalStorageDirectory();
 print(path);  // /storage/emulated/0
```

Now to create a Folder, you can use the below function:

```
//this will create a Folder in the storage/emulated/0
new Directory(externalDirectoryPath +'/YourfolderName')
  .create()
  .then((Directory directory) 
  {
    print(directory.path);
  });;
```

'

Comment: The plugin `ext_storage` uses a deprecated version of the Android embedding.
To avoid unexpected runtime failures, or future build failures, try to see if this plugin supports the Android V2 embedding. Otherwise, consider removing it since a future release of Flutter will remove these deprecated APIs.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit** post picture 2 to prove it work.

code snippet to create directory , file

```
    new Directory('/storage/emulated/0/MyFile').create()
    // The created directory is returned as a Future.
        .then((Directory directory) {
      print(directory.path);
    });

    new File('/storage/emulated/0/MyFile/test.txt').create(recursive: true)
        .then((File file) {
      // Stuff to do after file has been created...
      print('${file.path}');
    });

    var dir = Directory('/storage/emulated/0/MyFile');
    print('${dir.path}');
    print('${dir.list().toList()}');
```

full code for create directory and file

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:simple_permissions/simple_permissions.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        // This is the theme of your application.
        //
        // Try running your application with "flutter run". You'll see the
        // application has a blue toolbar. Then, without quitting the app, try
        // changing the primarySwatch below to Colors.green and then invoke
        // "hot reload" (press "r" in the console where you ran "flutter run",
        // or simply save your changes to "hot reload" in a Flutter IDE).
        // Notice that the counter didn't reset back to zero; the application
        // is not restarted.
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the home page of your application. It is stateful, meaning
  // that it has a State object (defined below) that contains fields that affect
  // how it looks.

  // This class is the configuration for the state. It holds the values (in this
  // case the title) provided by the parent (in this case the App widget) and
  // used by the build method of the State. Fields in a Widget subclass are
  // always marked "final".

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    new Directory('/storage/emulated/0/MyFile').create()
    // The created directory is returned as a Future.
        .then((Directory directory) {
      print(directory.path);
    });

    new File('/storage/emulated/0/MyFile/test.txt').create(recursive: true)
        .then((File file) {
      // Stuff to do after file has been created...
      print('${file.path}');
    });

    var dir = Directory('/storage/emulated/0/MyFile');
    print('${dir.path}');
    print('${dir.list().toList()}');


    setState(() {
      // This call to setState tells the Flutter framework that something has
      // changed in this State, which causes it to rerun the build method below
      // so that the display can reflect the updated values. If we changed
      // _counter without calling setState(), then the build method would not be
      // called again, and so nothing would appear to happen.
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SimplePermissions.requestPermission(Permission.WriteExternalStorage);

    // This method is rerun every time setState is called, for instance as done
    // by the _incrementCounter method above.
    //
    // The Flutter framework has been optimized to make rerunning build methods
    // fast, so that you can just rebuild anything that needs updating rather
    // than having to individually change instances of widgets.
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        // Here we take the value from the MyHomePage object that was created by
        // the App.build method, and use it to set our appbar title.
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        // Center is a layout widget. It takes a single child and positions it
        // in the middle of the parent.
        child: Column(
          // Column is also a layout widget. It takes a list of children and
          // arranges them vertically. By default, it sizes itself to fit its
          // children horizontally, and tries to be as tall as its parent.
          //
          // Invoke "debug painting" (press "p" in the console, choose the
          // "Toggle Debug Paint" action from the Flutter Inspector in Android
          // Studio, or the "Toggle Debug Paint" command in Visual Studio Code)
          // to see the wireframe for each widget.
          //
          // Column has various properties to control how it sizes itself and
          // how it positions its children. Here we use mainAxisAlignment to
          // center the children vertically; the main axis here is the vertical
          // axis because Columns are vertical (the cross axis would be
          // horizontal).
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
}
```

please use package flutter_file_manager https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_file_manager 
I have tested with real device, it works fine

full code

```
// framework
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

// packages
import 'package:flutter_file_manager/flutter_file_manager.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart' as p;
import 'package:simple_permissions/simple_permissions.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

@immutable
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //SimplePermissions.requestPermission(Permission.ReadExternalStorage);
    SimplePermissions.requestPermission(Permission.WriteExternalStorage);
    return new MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text("Flutter File Manager Demo"),
          ),
          body: FutureBuilder(
            future: _files(), // a previously-obtained Future<String> or null
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
              switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
                case ConnectionState.none:
                  return Text('Press button to start.');
                case ConnectionState.active:
                case ConnectionState.waiting:
                  return Text('Awaiting result...');
                case ConnectionState.done:
                  if (snapshot.hasError)
                    return Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
                  return snapshot.data != null
                      ? ListView.builder(
                          itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                          itemBuilder: (context, index) => Card(
                                  child: ListTile(
                                title: Column(children: [
                                  Text('Size: ' +
                                      snapshot.data[index]
                                          .statSync()
                                          .size
                                          .toString()),
                                  Text('Path: ' +
                                      snapshot.data[index].path.toString()),
                                  Text('Date: ' +
                                      snapshot.data[index]
                                          .statSync()
                                          .modified
                                          .toUtc()
                                          .toString())
                                ]),

                                subtitle: Text(
                                    "Extension: ${p.extension(snapshot.data[index].absolute.path).replaceFirst('.', '')}"), // getting extension
                              )))
                      : Center(
                          child: Text("Nothing!"),
                        );
              }
              return null; // unreachable
            },
          )),
    );
  }


  _files() async {
    var root = await getExternalStorageDirectory();
    var files = await FileManager(root: root).walk().toList();

    for(var i = 0;i<files.length;i++) {
      print("${files[i].path} ");
    }
      return files;
  }

}
```

working demo in emulator

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please provide package version name of  path_provider and simple_permissions

Comment: this is official demo. simple_permissions: ^0.1.9    path: '>=1.5.1 <3.0.0'   
   path_provider: '>=0.4.0 <3.0.0'

Comment: Not working.  it is showing path /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.demo/MyFile

Comment: In my samsung. I have checked.  if file created by app, it always appear as /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.abc.appname/files

Comment: In my samsung, ms office download file path is /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.microsoft.office.excel/files/Download/foregroundexcelsamsung/16.0.1.11601.20074

Comment: So what is the solution for /storage/emulated/0/ path?

Comment: This is a hard code path. every mobile vendor had a different path. this will not work in another vendor comany

Comment: I follow your question and create a demo path as your question to prove it work.

Comment: This is a hard code path. every mobile vendor had a different path. this will not work in another vendor comany

Comment: Sir please update your answer (Android 11)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, while Android SDK version >30 or 31 doesn't allow to read from other directories but you definitely read from your directory without any permission.

Add '//' + directory path & your problem will be resolved
So it means that your path will be '//'+ getExternalStorageDirectory())!.path

This is the code to save and retrieve the file work on both SDK > 30 and SDK =< 30.

```
final directory = (await getExternalStorageDirectory())!.path;
  ByteData? byteData =
      await (image.toByteData(format: ui.ImageByteFormat.png));
  Uint8List pngBytes = byteData!.buffer.asUint8List();
  File imgFile = new File('$directory/screenshot${rng.nextInt(2000)}.png');
  await imgFile.writeAsBytes(pngBytes);
  setState(() {
    _imageFile = imgFile;
  });
  // Add '//' + directory path & your problem will be resolved
  return '//'+imgFile.path;
```

First I'm saving the image in the directory then I'm reading it.

Comment: What about fetching the PDF from download directory and show.? can you please help me ? Akshay