# Flutter - I want to access my external storage

Tags: flutter

Flutter, How can I securely save videos from the network to the user's phone so I can play them again without using the internet, but users can't find them on their phones and only play them offline?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get files from external storage in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58075432/how-to-get-files-from-external-storage-in-flutter)

Comment: I think this answer does not match my question

Answer (score 0):

Does [this](https://www.fluttercampus.com/guide/184/how-to-save-image-and-video-files-in-download-folder-flutter/) answer your question?